# RPi.GPIO under Python 3

Tags: raspbian, rpi.gpio

Raspberry Pi2 B, standard Raspbian. Using RPi.GPIO, V3 installed as:

```
sudo apt-get install python-rpi.gpio python3-rpi.gpio
```

On line

```
import RPi.GPIO
```

I get

```
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/RPi/GPIO.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct
```

(either in interpreter or as code run as python3 myCode.py).

Any help please!?

Comment: It may be broken on jessie.  It requires Python < 3.3 but jessie uses Python 3.4.2.

Answer (score 1):

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)  # set board mode to Broadcom

GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT)  # set up pin 17
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)  # set up pin 18

GPIO.output(17, 1)  # turn on pin 17
GPIO.output(18, 1)  # turn on pin 18
```

from [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/python/more.md).

Answer (score 0):

It might be that your Pi is not updated.

Go to the command line on your pi and enter:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After running these commands, reinstall both the packages. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install RPi.GPIO
```

From Here: https://pypi.org/project/RPi.GPIO/#description